# Javascript form submit confirmation with redirect if true

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect

This javascript works to confirm the form before it's submitted, however i don't know what to do to add a redirect link if they confirm true, or if they confirm false:

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function cancelalert(){
return confirm("By clicking OK you are submitting the form.");
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
onclick="return cancelalert()"
```

Comment: If you redirect you will lose all data in the form. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Redirects are things that come from your **server**.

Comment: It's hard to explain, but basically the script will be dynamically called on the page... so with each javascript, the redirect link will change.

So basically i'm using 1 form and multiple javascript scripts, depending on the visitor (its a membership site and visitors have tags that will decide what they see)

Sounds like i might have to create a form for every javascript possibility i suppose.. I was able to get it to redirect before, but when i did, it'd submit the form regardless if they chose to not submit it or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning the result of `confirm` directly, put it in a variable and act accordingly:

```
var confirmed = confirm("By clicking OK you are submitting the form.");

if(confirmed)
{
  return true; // will sumbit the form. Do a redirect on the server side
}

// not confirmed. Show an alert or something
```

Comment: so i'd do the redirect on the form itself as a hidden field type deal?

Comment: @stebo - I don't know what that means. You can redirect to a different page, but then you lose all the information on the form.